# Excel Vba Multiple Ranges to powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel

Am working on power point automation using Excel Vba .Here is the code

```
'List of PPT Slides to Paste to
MySlideArray = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

'List of Excel Ranges to Copy from
MyRangeArray = Array(Sheet1.Range("$A$6:$I$16"), 
Sheet1.Range("$A$6:$I$8,$A$17:$I$33"), _
  Sheet1.Range("$A$6:$I$16"), Sheet1.Range("$A$6:$I$16"), 
Sheet1.Range("$A$6:$I$16"))

'Loop through Array data
For x = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)
'Copy Excel Range
MyRangeArray(x).Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = 
 myPresentation.Slides(MySlideArray(x)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2) 
'Excel 2007-2010
    Set shp = PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange 'Excel 2013
  On Error GoTo 0
```

The code is working ,the only problem is that the code

```
 Sheet1.Range("$A$6:$I$8,$A$17:$I$33")
```

Does not exclude the said cell ,Simply it include everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the rows that you don't want to take in the photo. Try this:

```
For x = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)
  With MyRangeArray(x)
    .Parent.Rows.Hidden = True    ' <-- hide all rows
    .EntireRow.Hidden = False     ' <-- show range's rows
    .Copy
    Set shp = myPresentation.Slides(MySlideArray(x)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2)
    .Parent.Rows.Hidden = False   ' <-- show back all rows
  End With
Next
```

---

[image]

Comment: How do i specify the size of each slide.How do i format each of the slide?